# show method on resource controller gets no data via keyname

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why the show method on my controller can't get data according to the slug.

this is my route :

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/berita',dashboardBeritaController::class);
```

this is my controller :

```
    public function show(Berita $berita)
{   
    // $berita = 
    return $berita;
    // return view('admin_layout.berita.lihat_berita',['ber' => $berita]);
}
```

This is my model :

```
class Berita extends Model {

use HasFactory,Sluggable;

protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

public function sluggable(): array
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'judul'
        ]
    ];
}
```

}

This is my blade :

```
<li><a class="btn btn-link text-info text-gradient px-1 mb-0" href="/dashboard/berita/{{$berita->slug}}"><i class="material-icons text-sm me-2">detail</i>Lihat</a></li>
```

when i trying return the $berita i got empty array :
[image]

can someone tell where the error lies?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

this is the result when i try dd($berita)
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHuVQ.png

Comment: Try `dd($berita);` instead of the return so we get more details that might help us to assist you.

Comment: i have add the result in my post above, can you help me fixed it?